# How to get the port from IPv6 Uri?

Tags: android, android-networking

Code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://[7a03:908:671:b520:ba27:bbff:ffff:fed2]:1234")
Log.d("debug", uri.getPort());  // result: -1
```

getPort() returns -1 instead of 1234.   How can the port of a Uri obtained without parsing the Uri's string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a known bug in Android. `android.net.Uri` returns incorrect values for IPv6. And it is still not fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37069493

I think you have to parse it manually (at least for now)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  This is all I need to know.  I can use URL to do the job.  I remember I had other issues with Uri.  It seems that Uri should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: it was fixed in 2018, BTW